# Prevent on-premise TFS from making a discussion comment ticket a related work item

Tags: tfs

Using on-premise Version 15.117.27024.0

In the discussion comments of ticket #12345, I may like to say

> @Username this ticket is resolved by #23456

When I do this and click save to commit the discussion comment, the workflow adds a Related work item link to the ticket mentioned. Is there a way to prevent this auto-relate behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> click save to commit the discussion comment, the workflow adds a
> Related work item link to the ticket mentioned

I tested it on my side and can't reproduce this issue, no links were added.

As long as you don’t select the suggestion that pops up or press enter, saving the work item directly will not generate the link

[image]

Comment: I do want to accept/select the selection, but I don't want it to be related. Are you using the CMMI template there, or the Agile template? We use the Agile template.

Comment: Yes, I use the Agile process. If you are referring to selecting the suggested work item that pops up, but you don’t want it to be in the form of a link, I’m afraid this cannot be achieved. This is by designed.

Comment: A hyperlink in the discussion comments to the other work item is fine, it's the relationship that's created I'd like to change.

Comment: In later versions of tfs there is such a design. For example you can see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3m2m.png) in server2019.

Comment: OK, looks like I need to wait for our on-premise instance to be upgraded to 2019.

Comment: I post a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1112091/need-hyperlink-feature-in-the-discussion-comments.html) for you in DC forum. You could vote that suggestion ticket and share your comment there,The product team would provide the updates if they view it.